# secure empty trash is the only option

Tags: snow-leopard, trash

I've been running Snow Leopard 10.6.8 for months. For some reason today I lost the ability to "regular" empty the trash. When I right-click the trash from the dock and select "Empty Trash" I'm presented with the "are you sure you want to secure empty the trash?" dialog. When I open the trash in Finder the button in the upper right corner says "secure empty trash". **How can I regain the ability to regular empty the trash?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick [google](https://www.google.com.au/search?rlz=1C1CHFA_enAU484AU484&sugexp=chrome,mod=2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=secure%20empty%20trash%20by%20default%20osx) found this [article](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/03/secure-empty-trash-mac-os-x/). You can enable secure empty trash as the default from the Finder preferences:

> For nearly every version of Mac OS X, there is also an option to
>   always securely empty the Trash, enabled within the Advanced Finder
>   preferences. If you regularly work with private data this is a good
>   feature to turn on.

[image: Secure Delete Trash]